# How Do I Load a Scene into V-REP using vrep-api-python?

Tags: python

Using the [vrep-api-python](https://github.com/Troxid/vrep-api-python) Python wrapper for the [V-REP robot simulator](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/), I am trying - but failing - to load a scene in the the simulator using the wrapped [`simxLoadScene()`](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/helpFiles/en/remoteApiFunctions.htm#simxLoadScene) function with a server side file:

```
from pyrep import VRep
from pyrep.vrep.vrep import simxLoadScene
from pyrep.vrep import vrep as v
from pyrep.common import ReturnCommandError

class sceneloader:

    def __init__(self, api: VRep):
        self._api = api
        self._def_op_mode = v.simx_opmode_oneshot_wait
        self.id = api._id

    def loadScene(self,path):
        clientID=self.id
        res = simxLoadScene(clientID, path, 0xFF, self._def_op_mode)
        print(res)

        if res != v.simx_return_ok:
            raise ReturnCommandError(res)

scene='/vagrant/scenes/Pioneer.ttt'
with VRep.connect("127.0.0.1", 19997) as api:
    r=sceneloader(api)
    r.loadScene(scene)
```

But it just throws a server error?